# site reported secure and insecure at the same time by firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, iis, certificate

On a particular website, in firefox, I click the lock in the address bar to see if the connection is secure. It is reported secure, see first image, it also says which CA verified the certificate. All seems well but if I click on more information, i get what is shown on the second image, firefox suddenly reports that the site is not encrypted. The website runs on IIS. This happens with both internal CA issued certificate (the ca is imported into firefox as trustworthy root) as well as with letsencrypt issued certificate. Neither internet explorer nor chrome find any anomalies and report the site as trustworthy and all certificates in order. Why is this happening and what kind of problem does this indicate? (i have another server at the same site running also IIS with exchange where the certificate shows correctly in firefox)
[image]
[image]

Comment: It sounds just like you have enabled HTTPS binding for your website but forgot to enable SSL in IIS manager->SSL settings->Require SSL. So the connection connect via https but didn't use ssl encryption indeed.

Comment: @JokiesDing I don't think that this is the problem. For once, it is enabled and second, all other browser feel that ssl is ok, ssltest of ssllab.com gives B only for enabled tls 1.0 and 1.1. Also firefox initially reports that the connection is secure and verified by letsencrypt but when I click on details, it show that it is no longer secure.